# An issue with <h1> position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like the `h1` to be shown on the top of the container but using the following code is appears on the bottom instead.

```css
/*RESETCSS*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* remember to define focus styles! */

 :focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: "" "";
}

body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}


/*SITE*/

.site {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 250px;
}

.site-login {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.site-login-leftimg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

.site-login-form-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.form-box {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.form-header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div class="site-login">
    <div class="site-login-leftimg"></div>
    <div class="site-login-form-container">
      <div class="form-box">
        <div class="form-header">
          <h1>hi</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can have a look at the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq2zpm7k/8/)
I can't find a reason for it to appear in that place.

Comment: Please add to your question, where do you wan the `h1` to be placed

Comment: done, but I think that normally it go on the top..

Comment: Hum the float left in .site-login-leftimg, remove it. And remove height 100% from site-login-form-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.site-login-leftimg` fills the full height (`100%`) of its parent container, `.site-login`. As a result, the rest of the content is positioned *below* that content. You may want to set your elements' flow to [`inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) so that the image and the container sit side-by-side:

```
.site-login {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You'll also likely have to adjust the widths of your elements so they fit side-by-side.

Consider using a grid system to handle this layout abstraction for you: [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Also take into account there is a .form-box give is a top: 20% offset from the top, if you want to position h1 at the very top.